# File upload error in php

Tags: php, javascript, html

How do I really know if I am passing a file to the server, via a file upload option?

i) I use a form as follows:

```
<form name = "someForm" id = "someForm" method = "post" action = "saveFile.php">                
    <input type = "file" name = "upload1" id = "upload1" />
    <input type = "file" name = "upload2" id = "upload2" />                     
    <input type = "file" name = "upload3" id = "upload3" />
    <input type = "submit" id = "btnSubmit" value = "Submit" />
</form>
```

ii) In saveFile.php, I use:

say:

```
echo $_FILES['upload1']["size"];
```

apart from others, but I get an **Undefined index: upload1** error, but not when, I use:

```
echo $_POST['upload1'];  //returns filename
```

Comment: Can you post some more code? Where are you storing the files on the server? Windows or Linux / Unix?

Comment: Windows. Storing on the server. I need to check the size of the file, and any mention using $_FILES reports an error.

Comment: You get "Undefined index: uploadSource1" but the code above it should be looking for the index "upload1" .. Is this the exact same code generating that error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify the `<form>` enctype to `"multipart/form-data"`:

```
<form enctype = "multipart/form-data" name = "someForm" id = "someForm" method = "post" action = "saveFile.php">                
    <input type = "file" name = "upload1" id = "upload1" />
    <input type = "file" name = "upload2" id = "upload2" />                     
    <input type = "file" name = "upload3" id = "upload3" />
    <input type = "submit" id = "btnSubmit" value = "Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<form name="someForm" id="someForm" method="post"
    action="saveFile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Enctype is required for upload of files.

You can access them by `$_FILES` not `$_POST`, nor `$_GET`:

```
echo $_FILES['upload1']['size'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Files are saved in:

```
print_r($_FILES); // NOT IN POST
```